# Putting an icon on FullCalendar's header

Tags: fullcalendar, font-awesome

I put a CustomButton on FullCalendar's header but i need to put an font-awesome icon.

```
           customButtons: {
                btnBloquearAgenda: {
                    icon: 'fa fa-lock',
                    click: function() {
                        alert('clicked the custom button!');
                    }
                }
            },

            header: {
                left: 'prev,next',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'btnBloquearAgenda agendaDay,agendaWeek,month'
            },
```

The button is showing "Undefined".

Comment: Just for your information: `fa fa-lock` stands for font-awesome, not bootstrap twitter. This is a class based system. Check this thread for the information you seek: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33285716/add-font-awesome-icon-to-full-calendar-title/33288946#33288946

Answer (score 5):

The icon value is appended to 'fc-icon-' and added as a class to the button's span element, i.e.

```
            btnBloquearAgenda: {
                icon: 'fa fa-lock',
                click: function() {
                    alert('clicked the custom button!');
                }
            }
```

Would result in

```
<button type="button" class="fc-btnBloquearAgenda-button fc-button fc-state-default fc-corner-right">
<span class="fc-icon fc-icon-fa fa-lock"></span>
</button>
```

My work around was to just add an extra "fa" to the icon value

```
       customButtons: {
            btnBloquearAgenda: {
                icon: 'fa fa fa-lock',
                click: function() {
                    alert('clicked the custom button!');
                }
            }
        },

        header: {
            left: 'prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'btnBloquearAgenda agendaDay,agendaWeek,month'
        },
```

Result:

```
<button type="button" class="fc-btnBloquearAgenda-button fc-button fc-state-default fc-corner-right">
<span class="fc-icon fc-icon-fa fa fa-lock"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me because fc-icon class uses the following rule : font-family: "fcicons" !important;

So you have to override this with

.fc-icon.fc-icon-fa {
    font-family: "FontAwesome" !important;
}

Comment: 1. $("button.fc-btnBloquearAgenda-button span").removeClass();
2. $("button.fc-btnBloquearAgenda-button span").html('<i class="fa fa-lock"></i>');
 --- I have fixed this issue using these lines fo code.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, just use some jquery to replace the buttontext.

```
$(".fc-today-button").html('<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>');
```

Answer (score 0):

to put the icon on FullCalendar's header without changing the code, 
try it with css,

put this one in diplay:

```
 viewDisplay   : function(view) {
     $(".fc-button-month").find(".fc-button-content").addClass("icocon");
 },
```

CSS

```
.icocon:before{
  font-family: "FontAwesome";  
  content: "\f133\00a0";
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used @user3776999's answer it worked in version 5. But when calendar rerendered, icons duplicated one by one. To fix duplication add this script tag before your js.

```html
<script>
   window.FontAwesomeConfig = { autoReplaceSvg: 'nest' }
</script>
```

https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/5544

Answer (score 0):

To use fontawesome icons just add to your css next code:

```
.fc-icon.fc-icon-fa { 
    font-family: "FontAwesome" !important; 
}
```

In button configuration use:

```
customButtons: {
                printButton: {
                  text: '',
                  icon: 'fa fa fa-print',
                  click: function() {
                    window.print();
                  }
                }
            },
```