# fullcalendar.js v4 - How to set html in title for list view?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

Got the following from the following. Unfortunately I could not make a comment because I have too few points.
[fullcalendar.js v4 - How to set html in title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56033273/fullcalendar-js-v4-how-to-set-html-in-title)

```
  eventRender: function(info) {
  info.el.querySelector('.fc-title').innerHTML = "<i>" + info.event.title + "</i>";
  }
```

When I tried the following, it works for month, week and day views. Unfortunately it does not work for list view. What did I do wrong?

Comment: "What did I do wrong?"... Did it occur to you that the appearance of a list view is quite different to the other views, and maybe you should take a look at the HTML used to create it, to see if that's different too? I guess you didn't inspect the HTML of a List View (using your browser's Developer Tools) to find out what element you could target instead. If you did, you'd have found HTML such as `<td class="fc-list-item-title fc-widget-content"><a>Sales Meeting</a></td>`. `fc-list-item-title` is probably a good class to target, therefore.

Comment: You correct. I should have looked in more deeply. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for the advice @ADyson.

Here is the working solution for me.

```
    if (info.el.querySelector('.fc-list-item-title') !== null){
      info.el.querySelector('.fc-list-item-title').innerHTML = "<span style=\"color:green;font-size:14px;\">Reading</span><br>";
    }

    if (info.el.querySelector('.fc-title') !== null){
      info.el.querySelector('.fc-title').innerHTML = "<span style=\"color:green;font-size:14px;\">Reading</span><br>";

    }
```