# FullCalendar display HTML in event title

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am updating my Fullcalendar install to V4. I am feeding mine via JSON and I have HTML (some FontAwsome Icons) in my event title. Here is my old V3 code to render my elements:

```
$(function() {
  $('#calendars').fullCalendar({
    events: '/activities/calendar.json',
    contentHeight: 750,
    displayEventTime: false,
    header: {
      left: '',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'today prev,next'
    },
    businessHours: {
      dow: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    },
    handleWindowResize: true,
    eventLimit: 2,
    eventLimitClick: 'popover',
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
      element.find('.fc-title').html(event.title);
    }
  });
});
```

The `eventRender:` is what fails.  The new docs don't clearly explain how I my convert this to the new version.  With this code in place my calendar simply fails to load with json parse error in the console.  If I remove it it works but my HTML is rendered as plain text.  I am sure I am missing something obvious and easy here.  My JS skill set is not that great.

Comment: Can you show precisely what you've done for V4 please, and specifically what the exact error is? In the meantime here's a simple example of how to use eventRender specifically in v4, maybe that will help you without needing to share further info with us: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56033273/fullcalendar-js-v4-how-to-set-html-in-title

Comment: That was pretty much what I found in on of the issues on GitHub.  I wish I had come across your post earlier.  Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some stubmling around I found this:

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('timeline');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      events: '/activities/timeline.json',
      plugins: [ 'resourceTimeline', 'interaction' ],
      header: {
        left: 'prev,today,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'resourceTimelineWeek,resourceTimelineMonth,resourceTimelineYear, '
      },
      eventRender: function(info) {
        info.el.querySelectorAll('.fc-title')[0].innerHTML = info.el.querySelectorAll('.fc-title')[0].innerText;
      }
    });

    calendar.render();
  });
```

I am open to alternate cleaner answers.

Comment: this looks like it would just replace the text with itself??

Comment: It does work - without this the html is rendered as text i.e. "\<span>span text\</span>".

Comment: oh I see, I didn't realise you had HTML in your title, I see now you mentioned it in the question but didn't see it as significant to the issue at the time.

Answer (score 8):

As of FullCalendar v5 you can use eventContent.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   let calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
   let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
            
      events: [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "First Line<br>Second Line",
                "start": "2022-06-04",
                "end": null,
                "allDay": true,
                "editable": true,
                "className": "badge-soft-warning",
           
            }
        ],

      eventContent: function( info ) {
          return {html: info.event.title};
      }

    });
    calendar.render();
})
```

Comment: Please add supporting details to your answer to improve it.