# In fullcalendar error adding button to event

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

In my laravel-fullcalendar app I want to add some buttons with jsvascript function to events
and looking at this [Add font awesome icon to full calendar title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33285716/add-font-awesome-icon-to-full-calendar-title)
example with decision I make it as :

```
window.calendarEventsObject = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
plugins: ['dayGrid'],

eventRender: function (eventInfo, element) {
    console.log("eventRender   eventInfo::")
    console.log(eventInfo)
    console.log("eventRender   eventInfo.event::")
    console.log(eventInfo.event)

    console.log("element::")
    console.log( element )


    console.log("eventInfo.el::")
    console.log( eventInfo.el )

    eventInfo.event.el.find(".fc-title").prepend("<i class='fa fa-external-link'></i>");

    var tooltip = new Tooltip(eventInfo.el, {        // example : https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-tooltip-demo
        title: 'HTREDSA', //eventInfo.event.extendedProps.description,
        placement: 'top',
        trigger: 'hover',
        container: 'body'
    });


},

events: eventsList,

header: {
    left: 'LEFT98',
    center: 'title123',
    right: 'Right 444'
},

showNonCurrentDates: false,

editable: true,
allDaySlot: true,
selectable: true,
selectHelper: true,
selectOverlap: false,
fixedWeekCount: false,

aspectRatio: 0.4,
height: 700,

select: function (start, end) {
    alert( "select:::"+var_dump(-50) )
    var title = "Available";
    var evid = SaveEvent(start, end, '1');
    $('#events_calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
},

eventClick: function (clickObj) {
    alert( "eventClick clickObj.el::"+var_dump(clickObj.el) )
    if (clickObj.el.href != "") {
        // alert( "::"+var_dump(-4) )
        let el_href = clickObj.el.href
        clickObj.el.href = ""
        window.open(el_href, "_blank");
        // clickObj.event.preventDefault();
        alert( "::"+var_dump(-41) )
        return false;
    }
    return false;
},
});
```

But debugging in console I see that the second parameter of eventRender function element is empty in my case.
I tried to get access to elemnt eventInfo by 1st parameter, but Failed:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/THL4D.jpg

How to add button to fullcalendar event ?

```
  "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
  "maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar": "^1.3",
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found a decision for fullcalendar 4 without jquery methods :

```
eventRender: function (eventInfo) {
    eventInfo.el.querySelector('.fc-title').append("Some additive Text ");
```

It works!